# "An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory” NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I am getting this error while creating SessionFactory. Here is the code, if some can check this out.

```
    class NHibernateHelper {

    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory {
        get {
            if (_sessionFactory == null) {
                InitializeSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeSessionFactory() {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure().
            Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString
            ("Server=tcp:z4m56fgh.database.windows.net,1433;Database=db;User ID=user;Password=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;").
            ShowSql()).
            Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<House>()).
            ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true)).
            BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession() {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Mappings:

```
   public class HouseMap : ClassMap<House> {

    public HouseMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Owner).Cascade.All();
        References(x => x.Rooms).Cascade.All();
        References(x => x.Consumptions).Cascade.All();
    }
}

    public class ConsumptionMap : ClassMap<Consumption> {

    public ConsumptionMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Type);
        Map(x => x.AvgDay);
        Map(x => x.AvgMonth);
        Map(x => x.AvgYear);
    }
}

   public class RoomMap : ClassMap<Room> {

    public RoomMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Number);
        Component<TemperatureData>(x => x.TemperatureData,
            t => {
                t.Map(x => x.TemperatureCurrent, "Current");
                t.Map(x => x.TemperatureSet, "Set");
            });
        Component<RoomFeatures>(x => x.Features,
            f => {
                f.Map(x => x.Shutters, "ShuttersUp");
                f.Map(x => x.Lights, "LightsOn");
            });
    }
}
```

This exact class NHibernateHelper works with another Model, so it must be something wrong with my mappings. Also, it still does not work if i exclude everything from HouseMap, i.e. comment on the References.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being a little difficult to realize what is the source of your problem without the classes, although, a guess would be at the **Consumptions** property. If it is a list (as it seems by its name) it should be mapped with **HasMany** instead of **References**.

Besides, maybe you could attach the stack trace with the **InnerException**. This could give us a clue.